# Upper bound of the integral $\frac{a^{n}}{n!}\int_{0}^{1} e^{at} t^{n}(1-t)^{n}dt$.

Tags: integration, irrational-numbers, integral-inequality, upper-lower-bounds, legendre-polynomials

I came across this integral in a proof related to using the Legendre polynomial to establish irrationality.

> $$
> I_{n}=(-1)^{n} \frac{a^{n}}{n!} \int\limits_{0}^{1} e^{at} t^{n}(1-t)^{n}dt $$

The author then assumed that this upper bound was trivial.

$$|I_{n}|<|\frac{a}{n}|^{n} \frac{e^{a}}{n!} $$

But,I do not understand how this bound was obtained.Perhaps I missed something very simple.I'd be grateful if someone could show how this bound was obtained.

Comment: Isn't $$|I_{n}|<|\frac{a}{4}|^{n} \frac{e^{a}}{n!}$$

Comment: Use $$\int_0^1 t^n(1-t)^n\,dt=\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$$ to find a tighter bound.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when $0\leq t\leq1$, then $e^{at}\leq e^{a}$, and $t(1-t)=t-t^2$ takes it's maximum at $t=\dfrac12$, it is easy to find the uper bound which is trivial now!

Comment: Use $$\int_0^1 t^n(1-t)^n\,dt=\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$$ to find a tighter bound

Comment: @MarkViola might this equality to give what the questioner wanted with $n$ instead of $4$ in denominator?

Comment: I don't believe so.  I did a quick calculation.   Indeed the bound with $4$ is higher than the one using this result.  But using Stirling's Formula (approximation), this is $O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\,\,4^n}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the upper bound was explained earlier by [user 108128](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2872710/66418), but in this case it is much easier to get the closed form answer. 

 Applying the identity (see *Prudnikov A. P., Brychkov Yu. A., Marichev O. I. Integrals and Series. Volume 1: Elementary Functions. Gordon & Breach Science Publishers / CRC Press. New York-London.(1986)*):
$$\int\limits_{0}^{a} e^{-px} x^{\alpha-1}(a-x)^{\alpha-1}dx=\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\alpha)\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)^{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}e^{\frac{-ap}{2}}I_{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{ap}{2}\right)$$
ans after all the simplifications one can get:
$$(-1)^{n} \frac{a^{n}}{n!} \int\limits_{0}^{1} e^{at} t^{n}(1-t)^{n}dt=(-1)^n \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{a}} e^{a/2}I_{n+\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right),$$
where $I_{n+\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)$-is the modified Bessel function.

Hence for further bounding one can use the Bessel function approximation.

Answer (score 0):

$$I_{n}=(-1)^{n} \frac{a^{n}}{n!} \int\limits_{0}^{1} e^{at} t^{n}(1-t)^{n}dt$$
if we consider the part of the function $e^{at}t^n(1-t)^n$ we can see that the maximum of this function in the range $(0,1)$ is always much less than $e^a$ so the integral must also be less that $e^a$ by considering the area under the curve as a rectangle of height $e^a$ and length 1 stated by the limits of the integral.

We could now consider the integral simply as $$I_n<(-1)^n\frac{a^n}{n!}e^a\,\therefore\,|I_n|<\frac{a^n}{n!}e^a$$ then notice that the integral is always less than $\frac{e^a}{n!}$ and approximate $n!=n^n$

This reasoning is close I guess.